Hue REST API to execute impala query
Currently I am working on a python script where I am calling Hue REST API from this official documentation to execute impala queries. Earlier I was using from impala.dbapi import connect to connect to impala services but recent security changes in our organization we are no more allowed to do it, so I thought to call using API way.
After converting the CURL command to REST api, I have below code:
import requests
import time

HUE_BASE_URL = "http://xyzserver.com:8888/notebook/api"
LOGIN_URL = f"http://xyzserver.com:8888/hue/accounts/login/?fromModal=true"
HIVE_DATABASE = "default"


session = requests.Session()

def get_csrf_and_cookies():
    # Step 1: Perform a GET request to get the initial csrf token and session cookies
    response = session.get(LOGIN_URL)
    csrf_token = session.cookies.get('csrftoken')
    session_id = session.cookies.get('sessionid')
    
    if csrf_token and session_id:
        print(f"CSRF Token: {csrf_token}")
        print(f"Session ID: {session_id}")
        return csrf_token, session_id
    else:
        raise Exception("Failed to retrieve CSRF token or session ID.")

def login(csrf_token, session_id, username='demo', password='demo123'):
    # Step 2: Perform login POST request with the csrf token and session ID
    login_data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
    headers = {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
    }
    cookies = {
        'csrftoken': csrf_token,
        'sessionid': session_id
    }
    
    response = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Login successful.")
        return session.cookies.get('csrftoken'), session.cookies.get('sessionid')  # Get fresh csrf and session cookies
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Login failed with status code {response.status_code}.")

def create_notebook(csrf_token, session_id):
    url = f"{HUE_BASE_URL}/create_notebook"
    data = {
        "type": "impala",
        "directory_uuid": ""
    }
    headers = {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
    }
    cookies = {
        'csrftoken': csrf_token,
        'sessionid': session_id
    }
    
    response = session.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    print('in create notebook')
    if response.status_code == 200:
        try:
            notebook_info = response.json()
            notebook_id = notebook_info.get('notebook_id')
            print(f"Notebook created, notebook_id: {notebook_id}")
            return notebook_id
        except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
            print("Failed to parse JSON. Raw response:")
            print(response.text)
            return None
    else:
        print(f"Error creating notebook. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return None

def execute_hive_query(query, notebook_id, csrf_token, session_id):
    url = f"{HUE_BASE_URL}/execute/impala"
    data = {
    "executable": f'{{"statement":"{query}","database":"{HIVE_DATABASE}"}}',
    "notebook": f'{{"id":"{notebook_id}", "type":"query-impala", "initialType":"impala", "database":"default","isHistory":true,"snippets":[{{"id":null,"statement_raw":"{query}","type":"impala","variables":[]}}],"name":"","isSaved":false,"sessions":[]}}',
    "snippet": f'{{"id":1,"type":"impala","result":"","statement":"{query}","properties":{{}}}}'
    }

    headers = {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
    }
    cookies = {
        'csrftoken': csrf_token,
        'sessionid': session_id
    }
    response = session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    print('Response in execute query')
    print(response)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json()
        print(result)
        history_id = result.get('history_id')
        print(f"Query executed, history_id: {history_id}")
        return history_id
    else:
        print(f"Error executing query: {response.status_code}")
        return None
def run_hive_query(query):
    # Step 1: Get CSRF token and cookies
    csrf_token, session_id = get_csrf_and_cookies()
    
    # Step 2: Login and get fresh tokens and cookies
    csrf_token, session_id = login(csrf_token, session_id)

    # Step 3: Create a notebook and get its ID
    notebook_id = create_notebook(csrf_token, session_id)
    if not notebook_id:
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    query = "SHOW TABLES"
    run_hive_query(query)

The get_csrf_and_cookies & login function works properly and I am getting proper csrftoken and sessionid. The problem happends when it calls create_notebook(), the response is 200 but in response I am getting HTML code and console it prints this from code:
response = session.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    print('in create notebook')
    if response.status_code == 200:
        try:
            notebook_info = response.json() #This line throws error because i am getting html, DON'T KNOW WHY!!!!!!

and response is :
<!DOCTYPE html>



<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hue 
 
    - Welcome to Hue
</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/desktop/art/favicon.2351422f4956.ico" />
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
 ...
 ...
 ...
// We collect only 2 path levels: not hostname, no IDs, no anchors...
var _pathName = location.pathname;
var _splits = _pathName.substr(1).split("/");
_pathName = _splits[0] + (_splits.length > 1 && $.trim(_splits[1]) != "" ? "/" + _splits[1] : "");

ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/remote/3.9.0-cdh5.16.2/' + (IS_HUE_4 ? '4/' : '3/') + _pathName
});

function trackOnGA(path) {
  if (typeof ga != "undefined" && ga != null) {
    ga('set', 'referrer', 'http://gethue.com'); // we force the referrer to prevent leaking sensitive information
    ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'page': '/remote/3.9.0-cdh5.16.2/' + (IS_HUE_4 ? '4/' : '3/') + path
    });
  }
}


</script>


  </body>
</html>

Any help is appreciated in letting me know why I am not getting proper JSON response and what I am doing wrong! Thanks
